# Google Adwords API 'getKeywordVariations' not working properly

Tags: google-ads-api

I'm trying to use the 'GetKeywordVariations' method of the google adwords API, documentation at [this page](http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/docs/developer/KeywordToolService.html#getKeywordVariations). According to the documentation, it should return these fields, including lastMonthSearchVolume. When I try this, i get all the fields except for lastMonthSearchVolume. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. i was using the older version of the API. Updating to the latest version fixed it .