# Does anyone use the Google Adwords API?

Tags: google-api, google-ads-api

I have been using the Google Adwords API for sometime, and i am starting to suspect that i have made an assumption.

Does anyone know if the 'GetKeywordVariations' returns keywords in order of relevance?

Comparing various keywords and their results with the Adwords website 
equivalent and I am seeing many differences.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Google API doc](http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/docs/developer/KeywordToolService.html#getKeywordVariations):

EDIT: (the page I linked to, has more than one method described):

> Given a list of SeedKeywords, returns
>   their variations in multiple lists
>   within KeywordVariations. Each list
>   represents a different kind of
>   variation.

Are you using the [latest version of the API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518460/google-adwords-api-getkeywordvariations-not-working-properly)?

Comment: There are two distinct keyword variation methods.  One, which you are referring to is the 'getKeywordsFromSite' where it clearly states it returns the keywords in order of relevance.

Comment: 'getKeywordVariations' on the other hand does not mention order signifcance.  And in my experience it doesn't seem to be returning the keywords in any particular order that i can descern

Comment: @Harry: well spotted! Completely missed that. Will update my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Yes latests version is being used.  I have posted to the offical google ADWords group - but getting an answer there is pretty much impossible

Answer (score 0):

Here is the section which describes how to match the results from the API with the results from the AdWords website. There are many search parameters you can set like location, language, etc. to help them align and match up results.

https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/targeting-idea-service#mapping_to_the_keyword_planner

> One of our most frequently asked questions around the TargetingIdeaService is: "Why do the TargetingIdeaService results differ from that of the Keyword Planner tool?"
>
> The reason is that a TargetingIdeaSelector can be configured with a number of different SearchParameters, and the returned results may differ significantly when different SearchParameters are used.

It won't return keywords in any particular order, but it provides the search volume and you can decide if it is relevant:

> Keyword idea with text 'toaster braun', category IDs (10009, 10410, 10412, 12798, 11566) and average monthly search volume '1900' was found.

This is for v201502.